# Question on elliptic curve of Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$: Any class there?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I want to present a brief question.

I'm curious whether there is any ***class*** of Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$ that we can assign them as rank $0$ by some particular property.

In other words, is there any local, if not global, condition known to $\{(a,b)\ \mid a\in \mathbb{Q}, b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ that $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ being rank $0$?

As long as I know the paper from [Bhargava et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1826) shows the biggest result regarding the rank of elliptic curves and the related conjectures so far, but I'm not sure whether there is any indication that my curiosity could be solved.

If my question was not clear please let me clarify them with further comments or edits.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends what you mean by class, but the answer is almost certainly no. For example, the results in the paper you cite apply to any family of elliptic curves defined by finitely many congruence conditions on $(a,b)$. In particular, in any such family, by Thm 3, a positive proportion of its members have rank $1$. Conjecturally, in any such family defined by congruence conditions, $50\%$ of curves will have each of rank $0$ and rank $1$.

Comment: Silverman's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/202080) gives one such collection: curves of the form $y^2 = x^3 + px$ where $p$ is a prime congruent to $7$ or $11$ mod $16$. You can find a more precise result in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Prop X.6.2.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn: Thanks!  I should look more into his textbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition X.6.2(c) of Silverman's [*The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-09494-6) gives one such collection of $a$ and $b$.

**Proposition**. Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $E$ be the elliptic curve
$$
E: y^2 = x^3 + px \, .
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{rank} E(\mathbb{Q}) + \dim_{\mathbb{F}_2} \operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})[2] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $p \equiv 7,11 \bmod{16}$},\\
1 & \text{if $p \equiv 3,5,13,15 \bmod{16}$},\\
2 & \text{if $p \equiv 1,9 \bmod{16}$},
\end{cases}
$$
where $\operatorname{Sha}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is the [Tate-Shafarevich group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group). In particular, we see that $a = 0$ and $b = p$ a prime congruent to $7,11 \bmod{16}$ yields an elliptic curve of rank $0$.

See [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48215/re-mordells-equation-y2-x3-k-and-perfect-numbers) for a special case of your question.